# Issue with positioning of header element

Tags: html, css

After some manipulations by me and some great users of this community this code was created.

Problem: Can't figure out the way to place headers after div element into the middle of the page under the social buttons.

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/a87ov0zt/15/ 
P.S: I apologize for not posting code here, but css looks kinda long...

Comment: You have to include your code when posting fiddle. Not all your code, but only the very relevant part of it. If your problem is on h1 tags, post your current html and the css for the relevant ids and classes. Also, even at your fiddle, no one needs all your css (ie. nav codes) so just delete anything unrelated and post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place the headers under the divs the you should create a `div` to contain both elements first, since they are both block level elements the `div` will naturally sit on top of the header. Do that for each 4 of your "media buttons".